# Logical AND in Java Regex

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to implement a logical AND in Java's Regexp? If the answer is yes, how can that be achieved?

Answer (score 8):

Logical ANDs in regexes are made up of a sequence of stacked lookahead assertions. For example:

```
(?=^.*foo)
(?=^.*bar)
(?=^.*glarch)
```

will match any string that contains all three of "foo", "bar", and "glarch", in any order, and even though some should overlap. (This assumes a customary interpretation of `^` and `.`.)

Of course, this property is not peculiar to Java.

Comment: Is this considered a single regex?

Comment: @EpsilonVector: Sure! It is if you use it that way. I’ve put the separate subregexes each on their own line for legibility. That would in Java require that one use either a leading `(?x)`  or `Pattern.COMMENTS` on the compilation so that the newline doesn’t count. Or you could simple catenate the three pieces directly using `+` or some other joining mechanism. I can update the answer to a full example in Java if you want, but it might help if you would showed me what the things you wanted AND’d together actually are.