# Regular expression to match all numeric characters except 5

Tags: c#, java, regex

When I want to match all numeric characters except 5 I use:

```
[^\D|5]
```

or

```
[^\D5]
```

or 
        [0-46-9]
or 
        [012346789]

When I want to match no numeric characters I can use:

```
[^\d]
```

or

```
[\D]
```

All of them work well. But when I use `[^^\d5]` or `[^^\d|5]` to match all numeric characters except 5, it doesn't work.

I want to use it in a lot of cases. For example, I want to match all `\p{P}` but not `\:`. Is there any way to use `^\d` to match all numeric character except 5?

Comment: How about: `([0-4]|[6-9])` ?

Comment: You can actually use a single character class: `[0-46-9]`.

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis, cool! I didn't know that! learn somthin new every day!  :)

Comment: No problem. I added more info on hyphens in character classes in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

#### You could match all digits except 5 using this:

```
[123467890]
```

There is no reason to use a shorthand version of everything. 
It makes no difference to the regex engine.

In fact, adding in alternation`|` and zero-length assertions`^` will only degrade your performance.

#### A shorter version would be:

```
[0-46-9]
```

#### Hyphen/Dash behavior inside character classes `[]`

Hyphens will specify a range inside character classes. You can look up an ASCII table to see what range you are doing, for example: `[ -Z]` actually matches ASCII 33 to 127.

---

## Edit:

Ok, now I have a better understanding of your requirements.
You need to be specific about what you need to match up front.

You can do this using negative/positive lookaheads:

```
(?!.*?5.*?)(?!.*?\p{Alpha}.*?)(\p{P}*?$|\p{L}*?$)
```

This will match under the following conditions:

- There is no number 5
- There is no character from the POSIX class: Alpha
- Any character with the Unicode property "letter" or "punctuation"

Comment: thanks for your help but I want to use operator(Example "is a number but not 5" or "not((not number) or 5)" like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws I can use [^\D5] but can not use [^^\d5]

Comment: There's no reason to use `[^^\d5]` if all you're trying to do is match any digit except 5.

Comment: I want to use it in a lot of cases. For example, I want to match all \p{L} but not \p{Alpha} how to do it ?

Comment: I think I understand what you are after. See the edit at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` is just `[0-9]`.  See the [Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for confirmation.

Just use `[0-46-9]`.  You can try it in a [regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/b9xug).

**UPDATE:**

Based on the requirement to leverage De Morgan's laws and use a logical complement per the OP's comment, here is my interpretation of the logical complement of `[^\D5]`.

`[^\D5]` essentially means "*NOT* (a non-digit character *OR* 5)".  Compare this to "*NOT* (A *OR* B)" in the referenced [Wikipedia article on De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

What we need then is "(*NOT* a non-digit character) *AND* (*NOT* 5)".  Compare this to "(*NOT* A) *AND* (*NOT* B)" in the referenced Wikipedia article.

Here then is my interpretation of logically complementing `[^\D5]` using [a sequence of lookahead expressions for logical ANDing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6082154/1810429):

```
(?!\D)(?!5).
```

No, it does not use double negation by `^^`; this does not work as you have found; but the above logical complement essentially means what we want in regexese - "(*NOT* a non-digit character) *AND* (*NOT* 5)" - applied to a single character (i.e. `.`).

You can see in a [follow-on regex fiddle](http://fiddle.re/nm7zg) that the above logical complement yields the same results as `[^\D5]` like it should.

Comment: thanks for your help but I want to use operator(Example "is a number but not 5" or "not((not number) or 5)" like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws I can use [^\D5] but can not use [^^\d5]

Comment: Okay, I will provide an update with what I think is the logical complement of `[^\D5]`, as I submit that it is not `[^^\d5]`.

Comment: @MinhLe: While I agree with Vasili Syrakis as a practical matter, entertaining the possibility that whether this could be done simply intrigued you (as it came to intrigue me), I have provided an update with what I think is a true logical complement of `[^\D5]`.  What a brain teaser!

Comment: I want to use it in a lot of cases. For example, I want to match all \p{L} but not \p{Alpha}  how to do it ?

Comment: sorry for my poor English i have find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928277/regular-expression-match-all-pl-but-not-palpha Thank you very much!

Comment: @MinhLe: This is really a different question, but I am glad you found a solution. While I prefer the linked solution that you found, I think `(?=\p{L})(?!\p{Alpha}).` would technically work too. Even if the pattern needs a little tweaking to produce the desired result (since I am offering it off the top of my head rather than rigorously checking it, saving a related fiddle etcetera), it further demonstrates the general technique of expressing match criteria with a sequence of lookahead expressions for logical ANDing.