# Regular Expression match all \p{L} but not \p{Alpha}

Tags: java, regex, operator-keyword

How can I match all `\p{L}` but not `\p{Alpha}` in a regular expression?
Is it possible to implement a logical `AND` in Java's Regexp? If the answer is yes, how can that be achieved?

Comment: what regex did you try so far?

Comment: Is there a reason this is tagged both with java and C#?

Comment: @Kjartan because my server is java and my client program is c#

Comment: @MinhLe Ah, ok. Perhaps you need two versions of the RegEx then? If you want to search for the same match both on server- and client side, you might need one for Java, and a different one (?) for C#, as I understand they are not always equivalent. (This seems like a relatively simple case though, so perhaps they will be equivalent here).

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by using a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
[^\P{L}\p{Alpha}]
```

`[^\P{L}]` matches the same as `\p{L}`, but the negated character class makes it possible to subtract characters/properties from that set of characters.

Answer (score 5):

It *is* possible, but it is Java specific:

```
[\p{L}&&[^\p{Alpha}]]
```

(quote as appropriate in a Java string etc)

Comment: Very nice. Can also be written as `[\p{L}&&\P{Alpha}]`.

Comment: sorry I check it on this web http://www.myregextester.com/index.php#resultstab it dose not work with c# and java. is the web site wrong? if it wrong i will check it in my java program

Comment: This is definitely a valid Java regex -- but not in C#. Go with @TimPietzcker's solution, it Just Works(tm)